# Unable to Install SQLEXPR_x64_ENU 2012 on windows 8 (vc_red.msi)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

This error occurs every time when I try to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8 64bit,The Feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable
SQL Server Setup has encountered an error when running a Windows Installer file.
Windows Installer error message: The system cannot find the file specified.
Windows Installer file: d:\82c2346193c40f69152eb7\redist\VisualStudioShell\VC10SP1\vc_red.msi

Answer (score 0):

you can tack a look here and it works for me

[Unable to Install SQL Server Developer 2012 on windows 7 (vc_red.msi)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/d2d92984-1b47-454c-be36-29eb1f284e41/unable-to-install-sql-server-developer-2012-on-windows-7-vcredmsi?prof=required)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Windows 7 and the error message stumped me for a while.

Eventually I realised that the message was referring to my install of SQL 2008, and that the temporary location used during the install of 2008 was what the error was referring to. I guess 2012 needed to uninstall some 2008 bits and pieces.

In the end I rebuilt the temporary structure from my 2008 install and the installation continued successfully. Painful...